# Can we copy a sub directory to another sub directory?

Tags: directory, error-handling, copy, wordpress, helpfile

I have to copy wordpress from the give path to htcdocs directory :-/var/www/html/wordpress and I have to copy this wordpress to /opt/lampp/htcdocs .
Direct copy paste is not allowed. I tried different commands and ended up with errors

Comment: What 'errors' are you encountering?  If they're permission errors you need to copy things around with `sudo` on the command line.

Comment: I need command to copy sub-directories within the root directory. I am new Ubuntu user , so guide me accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer rsync for such a task:

```
rsync -a /var/www/html/wordpress/ /opt/lampp/htcdocs
```

should do the trick. If you run into permission errors, sudo might be your friend:

```
sudo rsync -a /var/www/html/wordpress/ /opt/lampp/htcdocs
```

btw: htcdocs seems to hold a typo, maybe you meant htdocs - right?

Comment: yeah it is htdocs . pardon me

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.